# How to find 2x2 matrix with non zero elements and repeated eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to find a 2x2 matrix with non zero elements that has eigenvalue = 1 repeated (double).

How can i do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about matrix similarity?

Comment: @Git Gud sorry but no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

Your $2\times2$ matrix should be of the form:

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right),$$

being its characteristic polynomial:

$$p(\lambda) = |M-\lambda I_2| = \lambda^2 - (a+d) \lambda +ad- bc $$

Since you want your eigenvalues, $\lambda$, to be both $1$, your characteristic polynomial must become:

$$p(\lambda) = (\lambda-1)^2 = \lambda^2 - 2\lambda + 1,$$

so this relations must be held for $a,b,c,d$ by comparing term by term:

$$a+d = 2, \quad ad-bc = 1,$$

and every matrix $M$ satisfying this will be your answer.

Note that $ad-bc = |M| = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 = 1$ and $a+d = \text{Tr}(M) = \lambda_1+ \lambda_2 = 2$.

I hope this is useful to you!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved me some good hours!

Comment: I realize now how simple it really was.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix you are searching for must have 
$$\chi = (\lambda-1)^2$$
as its Characteristic polynomial.

Thus your matrix given by $A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ must satisfy

$$\det (\mathcal{I_2}\lambda-A) = (\lambda-a)(\lambda-d)-bc \stackrel{!}{=}(\lambda-1)^2$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \lambda^2 -\lambda(a+d) + (ad-bc) = \lambda^2-2\lambda +1 $$
This is true *iff*

$$ a+d = 2 \,\, \wedge ad-bc = 1 $$

Now solving this system by Try&Error:

- If $a=1$ then $b$ or $c$ has to be $0$ $\longrightarrow$ *not a valid solution*
- If $a=2$ then $d$ has to be $0$ $\longrightarrow$ *not a valid solution*
- If $a=3$ then $bc$ hast to be $-4$. Chosing $b=2=-c$ gives as a solution

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ -2 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Think of what the characteristic polynomial would be. How can you build a matrix with a given characteristic polynomial? (There is one exceedingly simple such $2\times 2 $ matrix.)

Comment: I think the OP wants all elements to be different from zero and, if I got your hint correctly, this doesn't help.

Comment: @GitGud you're correct, i need all elements to be different from 0. thanks all of you for the answers

Answer (score 0):

You can check that this matrix does the trick:

$A_{2,2}= \begin{pmatrix}
1/3 & 4/3\\
-1/3 & 5/3
\end{pmatrix}$

The way I got it was to use matrix similarity. This matrix is similar to a matrix with $1$ as repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you, the matrix does the trick. I will look into matrix similarity to get an idea.